# Once choice in multiple choice

Tags: obiee

I am trying to use the filter function to get a count of all
candidates that have a bachelors degree or higher, problem is i can
get the count but if say a candidate has both a bachelors and a
masters, i only want one of the degrees. Question is there a way to
modify this code to make sure candidates that have multiple degrees
are counted only once?

```
FILTER("Fact - Count"."# of Applications" USING (("Candidate
Education"."Highest Level Education" IN('Bachelor' 's Degree',
'Higher Degree'))   AND ("Candidate Education"."Graduated" =
'Yes')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you nest it?

FILTER(FILTER(A USING B) USING C) ?